# How to link a library resources to a library in same project on android studio?

Tags: gradle, resources, aar

I have try to make a resource library, but fails. It works well in ideaJ(not gradle project) and eclipse.

For example in gradle,  my application is consist of three part:
1. main app
2. library 1
3. library 2 : resources

When I build 1 + 3 and 3's resources using in 1 is works well.
However build 1 + 2 + 3 and 3's resources using in 2 make a build crash:

error: package com.example.kwangjo.mylibrary.R does not exist.

Following is build.gradle files.

```
app : 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kwangjo.testdd"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':mylibrary')
}

library 1: 
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
~           
library 2:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':mylibrary')
}

setting.gradle
include ':app', ':mylibrary', ':mylibrary2'

what is the problem? It seems that aar file dose not provide resource R.class file for library build.

Anyone know how to enable this?
```

Comment: I don't understand why library 2 has compile project(':mylibrary')? Shouldn't it not include anything?  Besides, not finding R is a compile error, not a crash. Just try to clean and rebuild

Comment: Add another tag of "android" to attract better attention. Gradle may be used in other platforms.